# How are we going to deal with temperature related questions?

Tags: discussion

Right now we have [cooling](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cooling) (5) which I consider a good tag. We also have [temperature](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/temperature) (4) which I would love to get rid off rather sooner than later.

*Temperature* is not a good *category* of questions. It doesn't group areas of interesting into a useful topic.

Just to open up discussion, here are my initial thoughts regarding the current 3 questions. Please keep in mind that some of the tags I suggest here, don't exist yet.

1. [What is the temperature behaviour of a Raspberry Pi in an enclosure?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/548/what-is-the-temperature-behaviour-of-a-raspberry-pi-in-an-enclosure)
   Should be tagged [case](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/case), which it already is. Could also be tagged [cooling](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cooling) in addition.
2. [How do I monitor and/or control the temperature of the SoC?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/357/temperature-power-monitoring-control)
   Should be tagged [monitoring](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monitoring), [administration](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/administration), [controlling](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/controlling), [sensors](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sensors)
3. [What's the maximum / minimum running temperature?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/103/whats-the-maximum-minimum-running-temperature)
   Should be tagged [specifications](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specifications)
4. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/808/does-the-rasberry-pi-run-hot
   I'm slowly starting to think we **do** need a [temperature](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/temperature)...

#### Other questions in the same category

- [What are the maximum operating temperatures of the components?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/675/35)

Comment: If the result of this requires some synonyming, don't forget to post at http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/166/tag-synonyms-draft-list

Comment: Also this question: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/675/35

Comment: [#2](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/357/temperature-power-monitoring-control) is my question and I disagree with your choice of tags.  It has nothing to do with [tag:administration].  Also [tag:controlling] and [tag:sensors] would suggest the question is about peripherals which it is not.  I think tagging it [tag:cooling] was a mistake and I have now removed it.

Answer (score 10):

Maybe this should be turned around - the main tag should be [temperature](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/temperature), with [cooling](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cooling) set as a synonym for it.

Cooling is really a subset of the broader area of how hot things run, and therefore how to keep them cool enough to be stable.

Comment: I like the thought. The temperature tag just *feels* so unspecific. But I'm not even sure if that's a bad thing :\

Comment: I don't think the RPi site is going to get the question through-put to warrant being overly specific. If you've too many tags and not enough questions you almost end up with a tag per question.

Answer (score 6):

There is just one problem with [cooling](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cooling).

"Cooling" is the act of cooling something down.

So [What are the maximum operating temperatures of the components?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/675/what-are-the-maximum-operating-temperatures-of-the-components) should not be tagged [cooling](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cooling), as there is nothing in the question asking how to lower the maximum temperatures, or cool the device in some other way.

Comment: But someone interested in the topic of *cooling* might want to find **exactly** the information in that question. And making the information easy is to find is one goal of tags.

Comment: Fair point, but just doesn't sound right to me, the question is not about cooling.

Comment: Yeah, I know what you mean. It definitely shouldn't be the **only** tag.

Comment: Of course if you quantify it, you could consider [tag:cooling] to also indicate lack of cooling. Even if the question is asking how hot something would run, is that just another way of saying "Would I need some way to cool it?"

Comment: @GrahamWager That does feel like it's scraping the barrel somewhat when temperature covers all those issues in a straightforward manner...

Answer (score 4):

The appropriate tag for concerns with the board itself would be "thermal" or "thermal management"

Comment: [tag:thermal-management] seems like it should be the tag for all of these rather than cooling *or* temperature

Comment: That's probably more precise, but keep in mind that many people with questions will use more colloquial terms like temperature, heat, cooling, etc.   Thermal-management, if used, should definitely have aliases.

Answer (score 3):

I agree, temperature is a bad tag.

If you consider that tags are most useful for searching for questions under a specific topic, could you say for sure what questions would appear under it?

It is too diverse.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think temperature is a bad tag - I think cooling is too specific. Certainly not all questions in temperature could be moved sensible to cooling:

[What's the maximum / minimum running temperature?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/103/whats-the-maximum-minimum-running-temperature)

That question for instance is asking nothing to do with cooling at all, just the running temperature of the components.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that temperature can be used also for pehiperals questions (connecting/using temperature sensors). For example this one: [How to measure temperature?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1207/how-to-measure-temperature) (maybe it could be named differently to make it clear it is not about measuring temperature of RPi itself).

Comment: I think `tag:sensors` would be applicable in that case...

Answer (score 1):

Does that mean that one of our current moderators Mr @Goldilocks can not have a tag to apply to a question he might have with running an RPi in an outdoor location in his back-yard? After all it looks as though it gets decidedly chilly where he is and he might actually need `tag:heating` for such an external RPi usage on those cold, winter nights... 8-)

Comment: There is a way around this problem if you jump one of the 5V pins to ground, carefully pack the Pi in dry newspaper, and place it in a cardboard box with some holes punched around the sides before you plug it in.  See `tag:magic-blue-smoke`.

Comment: Oh, I was thinking more along the lines of rust and aluminium powder with a magnesium igniter but I guess yours is less _industrial_ and more homely!